# extracting/exporting images from a video at every scenechange

Tags: ffmpeg, video, ffprobe, analysis

How can I extract images from a video at each scene change (i.e. the 1st image from each new scene in a video) ?

FFmpeg is [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38205105/3161220) to be able to detect scene changes but I don't know how to adapt the FFmpeg parameters used there to this question.

I'd like to use a command line tool (like FFmpeg) for Windows.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex select='gt(scene,0.4)' -vsync vfr %03d.png`